# Adding Complex Click Events HoloLens

Tags: hololens, windows-mixed-reality

**Summary:**

- *Goal:* create a dynamic table of contents on start
- *Expected results:* if the user clicks button that corresponds to page x, the user will be directed to page x
- *Actual results:* if the user clicked button that corresponds to page x, the user will be directed to the last page

**What I have tried:**

- Followed the code for OnClick events listed on the MRTK documents https://microsoft.github.io/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/Documentation/README_Interactable.html

```cs
public static void AddOnClick(Interactable interactable)
{
    interactable.OnClick.AddListener(() => Debug.Log("Interactable clicked"));
}
```

- Looked into GitHub thread https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/4456
- Looked into the GitHub thread https://github.com/microsoft/MixedRealityToolkit-Unity/issues/5013

**Code:** TOC = Table of Contents

```cs
private void TOCpage()
{
    GameObject TOC = new GameObject(); // holds table of contents buttons
    for(int i = 1; 1 <= pages.Count - 1; i++)
    {
        GameObject TOCgameObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(TOCButtonPrefab);
        var TOCButton = TOCgameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
        TOCbutton.OnClick.AddListener(() => TaskOnClick(i));
    }
}

public void TaskOnClick(int TOCButtonNumber)
{
    Debug.Log("Table of contents button number " + TOCButtonNumber + " clicked");
}
```

If user clicks on TOCbutton for page 1, and there are 7 pages, the user is directed to page 7.

Answer (score 1):

> TOCbutton.OnClick.AddListener(() => TaskOnClick(i));

This happens because `i` is not local to the lambdas, but is defined in the outer scope, and it is accessed when the lambda is called — not when it is defined. At the end of the loop, the value of `i` is 7, so all the functions log 7.

Instead, you can create a local variable within the loop and assign it the value of the iteration variable or use `foreach` statement to do it under C#5.0 or later.

As a solution, you can refer to the following code:

```
        foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(1, pages.Count))
        {
           GameObject TOCgameObject = (GameObject)Instantiate(TOCButtonPrefab);
           var TOCButton = TOCgameObject.GetComponent<Interactable>();
           TOCbutton.OnClick.AddListener(() => TaskOnClick(i));
        }
```